# Why isnt the @Override method run?

Tags: android

I want to run the child @Override method but It doesnt work, I am fairly new to this and if someone could help that would be great!

This is the parrent class:

```
public class CentralClass {

     public void Test(){

     }
}
```

This is the Child class:

```
public class FileMethods extends CentralClass {

    @Override
    public void Test(){
        Log.v("refactor", "testtt");
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
CentralClass cc = new CentralClass();
cc.Test();
```

Comment: what do you mean that it doesnt work?

Comment: Need to see the code that uses the instance of those classes

Comment: Rod_Algonquin -> It Runs the Test() in the parent class, but not the on in The Child class

Comment: @Guus : As CChi says - edit your question and post the rest of the code which shows how you are using the `FileMethods` class.

Comment: That's normal because you instanciate the parent class, then only the Test() method of the parent is called. If you need the child Test() method to be called, you have to instanciate a child object like: FileMethods fm = new FileMethods();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is:

```
CentralClass cc = new FileMethods();
cc.Test();
```